# Detect blocked camera react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I need to detect that camera/webcam is blocked. I achieved on doing that, but the problem is that it will detect it after the second open not the first time I click block. I'm using `scandit-sdk-react` for the camera scanner.

My Scenario and what I'm trying to achieve :

- When I open scanner, the browser will ask to allow/block camera
- If I hit the block **FROM THE FIRST TIME** it will appear custom blocked popup

What I achieved is like below:

I open scanner for first time, and choose block

[image]
[image]

I close the scanner, then open it again

[image]

Here is the code:

```
const [cameraDenied, setCameraDenied] = useState(false);
const checkCameraDenied = async () => {
  try {
    const PermissionStatus = await navigator.permissions.query({
      name: "camera",
    });

    if (PermissionStatus.state === "denied") {
     setCameraDenied(true);
    }
   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
   }
};

useEffect(() => {
   checkCameraDenied();
}, []);

return (
  <>
    {cameraDenied && (
       <Modal type="cameraDenied" setShowModal={closeScanner} />
    )}
   </>
 )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I silently check camera permission in React-Native using Expo without launching the system dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601104/how-can-i-silently-check-camera-permission-in-react-native-using-expo-without-la)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

// filter on video inputs, and map to query object
const queries = devices
  .filter(({ kind }) => kind === "videoinput")
  .map(({ deviceId }) => ({ name: "camera", deviceId }));

const promises = queries.map((queryObj) =>
  navigator.permissions.query(queryObj)
);

try {
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  // log the state of each camera
  results.forEach(({ state }, i) => console.log("Camera", i, state));
} catch (error) {`enter code here`
  console.error(error);
}
```